# scheduling between two members of my community

Tags: icalendar, meeting-request, ischedulingservice

we have social media application and we have video calling but often the other person is not on the app so the call doesn't go through.  so just like calendy does for my business i want to allow members to send create a mutually good time to schedule a call.  - we have about 3,000 members -  this of course needs to stay within the app and not have sign in to another app or pay for 3,000 users - most don't even use the feature yet.  we would be open to both code or ideas to do this or even a third party link to create the meeting but seamless with the app. essentially it is mini calendy program between any two people in our membership ecosystem  - and too be clear this is with our app not website.

we haven't started this project yet - right now it would be done simply in a chat from one to the other saying Hey how about tomorrow at 8pm